# Adword script that pause's keywords where the final URL is a 404 redirect?

Tags: javascript, scripting, google-ads-api

Is it possible to create an Adwords script which pause's the keyword if the final URL redirects to a 404? And enables them when the URL is corrected?

I know the common Link Checker script but that only notifies you when a URL is wrong? It doesn't action anything.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Broon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code would look something like this:

```
function main(){

$_Keywords = AdWordsApp.keywords()
.get()

while ($_Keywords.hasNext())
{
    $_Keyword = $_Keywords.next()
    try {
        var $_Response = UrlFetchApp.fetch($_Keyword.urls().gerFinalUrl(), {muteHttpExceptions: true});
        $_ResponseCode = $_Response.getResponseCode();
    }   catch (e) {
        //Presuming something went wrong here
        $_Keyword.pause()
    }

    if ($_ResponseCode == 404)
    {
        $_Keyword.pause()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. Could the same be done for other problems, i.e. Sold out? Would the script be similar?:

Comment: Somewhat. Presuming you don't code in access to your product database, you would probably have to to something like UrlFetchApp.getContentText(), and then search that response for the text of "sold out".